# Ubuntu 20.04.2 with forgotten administrator password that won't reboot GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, password

My laptop died, so I had to start using my 2nd laptop, which has Ubuntu 20.04.2. This laptop hasn't been in use for over a year, and I have forgotten the administrator password. To change the password, I have tried pressing Shift and Esc on start up to reboot with GRUB, but it does not work. The computer either opens normally, or then the screen turns grey and nothing happens.

The computer hasn't had any updates for over a year, so it sorely needs them, but I cannot update anything without my password. To fix the issue of GRUB not working, I would also need my password. What can be done?

I also had the thought of changing the OS into Windows 10, will it still be possible without the password? Or is it possible to re-install the Ubuntu, again, without the password. My computer does not have a CD/DVD station.

Thank you for any help. I really am in a bind since this is the only working laptop I have at the moment, and I can't afford a new one.

Comment: It's always possible to reinstall any OS as it doesn't depend on what's already in the drive. But you may want to boot a live session and backup personal files. Easy if not encrypted, not possible otherwise.

Comment: The laptop is empty, so there's nothing I need to save from it. I suspect the laptop had Windows 10 on it before Ubuntu was installed, so I wanted to see if I could re-install Windows 10 by using the old registry key. Is it possible in any way to see the registry key without the administrator password? Or is my only way around it to first re-install Ubuntu, look for the registry key, and then install Windows 10?

Comment: Windows (OEM) licenses are stored in the EEPROM and/or at your Microsoft account, it's not a registry thing. If it were you wouldn't be able to access it anyway if Windows was removed and Ubuntu installed instead, obviously. So yes, you can reinstall the same as the original Windows and it'll activate fine. But this, again obviously, is NOT an Ubuntu question. You may want to ask at superuser.com in the future.

Comment: Thank you! I am still undecided which OS to keep, and my main problems are with the Ubuntu boot not working rn, which is why I posted here.

Comment: Questions about Ubuntu are on-topic. Questions about installing Windows obviously not. Do not mix the two. If you want to ask about Ubuntu, ask about Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind Sure but what's the point? If the OP wants to reinstall Windows, which again has nothing to do with Ubuntu, they can just do that and it'll activate as before, no license key required since it'll be read and used automatically.

Comment: well clearly I lack knowledge of windows  Last time I needed that it had to be typed during installation ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Since UEFI and Windows 8 back in 2012 this is how it rolls. It can't be done with BIOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have now tried to install both Ubuntu and Windows 10 on the laptop, but because I cannot enter the Ubuntu boot menu, I can't install it from the USB. I have tried pressing Esc, F2, F12 and Delete when restarting the laptop, but what I get is a flickering screen of commands for a couple minutes, and then the laptop just opens normally. I am at a loss. I can't update anything on this Ubuntu, and it's locking me out of installing any other OS. I still cannot remember the password, and cannot enter Boot menu to change the password.

Comment: I managed to remember my password, but I still cannot enter boot on the Ubuntu.

Comment: When I try to update anything on Ubuntu, it gives me this message: E:dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg -configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: Entering the boot menu is the laptop's Bios, not Ubuntu - which laptop is it? You can usually find out the boot menu key by online search ... it's usually one of the keys you've tried, or sometimes f10. Some laptops require you to hold fn and the f2 / f10 / f12 key, others just require the f2 / f10 / f12 without fn. Hold the correct key down whilst it's turning on ... or keep pressing it repeatedly as soon as you press the power button.